# aws sdk for mac os x application development

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, xcode4.2

I need to develop an application for MAC OS X, which will be uploading the chosen files to amazon web services. But for that I need aws sdk for mac. I haven't found any on the web. Is it possible to modify the [AWS SDK for iOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) so it can be used for Mac?

Also, the AWS SDK documentation doesn't explain how to upload files to S3. Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This is not off topic at all. It would be very helpful to find the AWS SDK for Mac OS.

Comment: This one make my day:
https://github.com/swift-aws/aws-sdk-appleos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by [a discussion on this topic](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56315) in the [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa), there doesn't seem to be an official AWS SDK for MacOS X yet, but the iOS version is close to useable. One contributor to that thread has posted [a modified version that allegedly works on MacOS X](https://github.com/tomandersen/aws-sdk-for-ios/) for at least some of the services. I don't have any personal experience with it, but it seems worth a look.

Comment: Really all I did was fork the iOS official version, then make some very minor changes - all there to simply satisfy the compiler, like using ifdefs around any iOS only code (not much), and swapping out some headers <UIKit> goes to <Cocoa>, etc. For a large project you might want to use your own fork, so you can personally see all the changes. I use it for S3, SimpleDB, SQS and IAM.

Comment: That's what I did, but I get a strange exception when I call the listBuckets method of the AmazonS3Client class. It says:
Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendString:
I have searched the whole SDK for appendString calls, but I didn't find anything. I find out that the error occurs when calling NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate: in AmazonS3Client on line 464.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Ok, I've tried it with the modified version from your answer, it works fine with this one. Still wondering why it didn't work...

Answer (score 9):

I've created a fork of the AWS iOS SDK which can be built and used for Mac OS X development. Check it out: https://github.com/amberdixon/aws-sdk-ios. In the readme, I've included instructions on how to build the Mac OS X version of the AWS iOS SDK framework. The tomandersen repo appears to use a much older version of the iOS SDK, the version I've created is a bit more current.

Comment: At that time, I managed it working with macOS without much mess with the code, but Amber thanks a lot for this, it will help others ...

Comment: i cant find the framework can you please put the step or screenshot for how can i find the framework after build the your suggest src/AWSiOSSDK.xcodeproj i open this project then build but did not find any framework :( plz help

Answer (score 5):

Following on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17155965/623999), I forked and modified v2.2 of the AWS SDK for iOS so it now builds for Mac OS X (tested in Yosemite 10.10.3): https://github.com/johnabender/aws-sdk-ios **Also checkout the `tvos` branch!**

They provide a command-line tool to package the SDK components as `.framework` objects. Run `Scripts/SdkPackage.sh AWSS3`, and it will build the S3 framework and any dependencies. Run `Scripts/Package.sh` to build all the frameworks. The built frameworks wind up in the root`/build` of your AWS SDK directory if you build them all.

But yikes, their documentation is awful. For example, if you want to use an access key instead of a Cognito identity, you have to go through the code and figure out how (at least it's possible!). Want to list an S3 bucket's contents? Good luck. Most of the required classes aren't even listed in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/%20documentation). And you'll have to include `libz.dylib` in your project to get it to build with the S3 SDK - they don't tell you that, either.

Anyway, here's some code to help anyone get started:

```
// This is helpful, also basically undocumented.
AWSLogger.defaultLogger().logLevel = .Verbose

let credentials = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKeyId, secretKey: secretAccessKey)
let config = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USWest2, credentialsProvider: credentials)

let listRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
listRequest.bucket = "mybucket"
listRequest.prefix = "folder/"

// The key name allows you to set up multiple, global S3 configurations
// -- in case you'd ever want to do that, in violation of OO programming principles.
// But there's no way to make S3 requests using only a local config.
AWSS3.registerS3WithConfiguration(config, forKey: "s3")

AWSS3.S3ForKey("s3").listObjects(listRequest).continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
    if task.error != nil {
        NSLog("error %@", task.error)
    }
    if task.result != nil {
        NSLog("finished %@", task.result!.description)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You are the receiver of the biggest virtual high five I have given all week!

Comment: @jab can you provide some details on how to use this.  I downloaded a ZIP archive but was unable to build it - it complained that my Mac was not a valid target?

Comment: Ok got it ! run the scripts !! Getting the following error though.
`** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
 CompileC build/AWSMobileAnalytics.build/Debug/AWSMobileAnalytics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AWSMobileAnalyticsIOSLifeCycleManager.o AWSMobileAnalytics/Internal/AWSMobileAnalyticsIOSLifeCycleManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error occurred, abort`

Comment: What exactly are you running? And are you trying to build for MacOS or tvOS? This error message isn't very helpful. It's possible the real error appeared pages and pages above this final abort message.

Comment: @jab So I built the framework using your source and added them to my project under Frameworks without running pod install for aws sdk (since i am getting rejected with the warning message saying they don't support osx). Now I am getting the following error message: `'AWSCore/AWSCore.h' file not found`. Is there something I am missing? Thank you very much!

Comment: @ChrisP it sounds like you need to add the frameworks to your project's build, in the project "general" settings under "linked frameworks and libraries" - exactly what you always have to do when not using CocoaPods.

Comment: Not sure if this is still supported (or really the right way to go as opposed to just using a Restful API, but I tried building and got the same error as Duncan. It seems that the root of the error is that it can't find UIKit/UIKit.h in AWSMobileAnalytics.
-- EDIT: Skipping over this seems fine - its just the mobile analytics that throws from what I've found. However, there's no AWSCognito included :/

Comment: I think what I did was simply remove UIKit imports and any code that referenced them. I'll take a look at this version again to see if I can repro. Regarding the API, it's fairly complicated and uses XML (ugh). As painful as it was to build the SDK, I still think it's easier than using the API directly.

Comment: Here's the changeset I used to compile it the first time: https://github.com/johnabender/aws-sdk-ios/commit/3a28e815161e7494a7490624c6cb1288df37838d As you can see, I basically just replaced UIKit with equivalent Cocoa calls until the build succeeded. Possibly I missed some?

Answer (score 0):

As Caleb mentioned: There is no official AWS SDK for OS X.

The easiest way to accomplish S3 file upload is using [`ASIHTTPRequest`](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request). It's a wrapper for CFNetwork, which is easy to use. A drawback is no ARC support, so you have to handle memory management on your own …

Comment: ASI is basically discontinued. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the AWS SDK for Mac to support prepopulating a db for my iOS app and was amazed that it didn't exist (considering how trivial it would be to produce as would be so similar to the iOS version). I downloaded the github MacOS SDKs mentioned by Amber above and the one mentioned in the AWS link above. However neither built straight off so I decided to modify the iOS SDK myself so I could understand what the process was. 
Here are the steps that I went through to get DynamoDB working in XCode 5.0.2 on MacOS 10.9:

1.Download the iOS AWS 1.7.0 SDK, duplicate the folder and rename the folder to aws-MacOS-sdk-1.7.0 (a small amount of conditional compilation and if/else in the build script would do away with this step)

2.Modify src/Scripts/Framework.sh - this is the build tool for all the AWS frameworks
 - Replace all four xcodebuild lines (30-39) with:

```
`xcodebuild -configuration Release -project "${PROJECT}.xcodeproj" -target "${PROJECT}" -sdk macosx10.9`
```

- Replace the lipo line (82-87) with:

  `FRAMEWORK_INPUT_MAC_FILES="build/Release/lib${PROJECT}.a"
  cp "$FRAMEWORK_INPUT_MAC_FILES" "$FRAMEWORK_DIR/Versions/Current/$FRAMEWORK_NAME"`

3.In the src folder there is an XCode project per framework, for each one you need:

- Change Project's Base SDK to latest OS X
- Change FTarget's Framework's SDKROOT to macosx10.9
- Ensure current scheme is set to Framework and build
- Fix compiler errors (I had a bunch of problems to do with @property, had to replace `<UIKit/UIKit.h>` with `<Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` here and there, and `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]` with `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString]`

To get DynamoDB working I had to build four frameworks - it was fairly painless

Comment: I cant seem to get rid of this error :: 'Cocoa/Cocoa.h' file not found.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the README of my project? Thanks.